# Kubernetes how to have pods initiate only during runtime through python?

Tags: python, kubernetes

In kubernetes, if I desired to have pods for a specific task not always required is it possible to have the system spin pods up for a given task when needed? Can this be managed through the backend code (in my instance python)? Do services need to be defined in a certain way in advance?

I found an api for docker management in [Python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), would this work for Kubernetes?

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for Knative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i have understood correctly you want to run the PODs when required not all the time.

in that case you can use the python client library of Kubernetes and manage the PODs or replicas of deployment.

you can deploy your service with replica count zero and once required you can scale up the pods using the client to as much required.

Kubernetes python client: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python

if your service is already running you can use this API :

```
GET /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/{namespace}/deployments/{name}/scale
```

here using just curl also you can spin up the replicas

```
API_URL="http://kubernetes:8080/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/{namespace}/deployments/{name}/scale"
curl  -H 'Accept: application/json' $API_URL > scale.json
# edit scale.json
curl -X PUT -d@scale.json -H 'Content-Type: application/json' $API_URL
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you want to achieve because you are not giving enough information. Here are some tools you migh want to check:

[keda](http://keda.sh) - event driven autoscaler, can scale down to zero

[k8s jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) - runs one time jobs

[knative](https://knative.dev/) - can scale down to zero

You can also just use k8s python client library to run a pod, make it do whatever you want and then delete it.